# How much data can one send from vertexshader to geometry/fragmentshader? (With blocks)

Tags: opengl, shader

I have a trivial question about shaders and how much data you can send between them, and how to calculate how much data one can send, with the gpu you have (or how to find this out).

I had a vertex shader program that had this code snip in it.

```
out VertexData {
    mat4 Object_To_World;
    mat4 World_To_View;
    mat4 View_To_Clip;
}VertexOut;
```

Just a note I had an equivilant "in" section in the fragmentshader.

With this code snip, my shader would not link and run.

p.s
I know this is probably is not the way to transfer such data, I just wanted to check out if i could do it, and what the limit would be, but i can't figure out how to calculate/find the limit in byte/bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query those limits with [`glGet*()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGet.xhtml) (assuming OpenGL 4)

Some enumerators of interest:

- `GL_MAX_VERTEX_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS` (at least 64)
- `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_INPUT_COMPONENTS` (at least 64)
- `GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_COMPONENTS` (at least 128)
- `GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_INPUT_COMPONENTS` (at least 128)
- `GL_MAX_VARYING_*`

The limits usually match for any combination of shader stages, at least the minimum values do. Depending on the GL version, one could rely on those minimum values.

You have 3x4x4 = 48 float components there. Even though these and other intermediate builtin values fit into the limits, consider to use uniform or buffer backed (uniform buffer, texture buffer) storage for invariant data.